# HTML pound/hash (#) links odd behavior - always leads to homepage rather than top of page

Tags: html, hyperlink

I am working with a particular OpenCart theme [here](http://journal.digital-atelier.com/2/fashion/beauty) and for whatever reason, any link with href="#", when clicked, always goes to the homepage. Normally it would cause the screen to jump to the top.

Try for yourself, at the reference link, click the address location link at the bottom-left of the footer. I cannot for the life of me determine why this theme is causing the `<a href="#">` links to behave this way.

Comment: 1. It has `<a href>` not `href="#"`. 2. No elements are there with `href="#"`. 3. Events are confusing it. So check the events.

Comment: @PraveenKumar That is false. Check the code again. The links are clearly: <a href="#">. If I could determine which event was causing the redirect, I wouldn't be asking.

Comment: The whole address differs when hovering the mouse. It must match the current address as well!

Comment: @RoyiNamir You are correct. Check the address location link to the right of the 800 #. Question has been edited.

Comment: @FurryWombat Would you like to see it wiht your own eyes? http://i.imgur.com/PvUiNjP.png?1

Comment: @PraveenKumar Please stop commenting on my question if you cannot read instructions. Never once did I indicate that the logo had anything to do with my question. Check the address location link in the bottom-left of the footer, as indicated above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of this tag :

```
<base href="http://journal.digital-atelier.com/2/">
```

in :

[image]

Remove it. and you'll see the expected behaviour.

You are right. You do supply pure `#` to the href ( investigating the html source , does show it).

*But* that line  above  affects its base address.

Comment: Royi, you are the MAN!!! No wonder this wasn't coming up under the FireBug. The whole time I imagined it was JavaScript/jQuery causing this to happen, and it was staring me in the face the whole time :) Thank you!!

Comment: Thanks. I saw the rendered html , you do supply pure #. so I thought if it is JS that makes the problem. searched through files in chrome , no sign for that class in JS context. so the only alternative is base.... :----> it was staring me in the face the whole time <----- lol , yes it did